# How to build a clustered recyclerview?

Tags: android

Already I researched several examples but no illuminating. How to scratch a list of documents totaling to pay per month.

As shown in the image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdQA9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:
[RecyclerViewStickyHeader](https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders)

Comment: Why deprecated library o.O

Comment: I want something more like the image. If you find I'll use that . Thank you!